# Returning result from Electron to React

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have an electron method to print:

```
ipcMain.on('print', (results, total) => {
    PosPrinter.print(print_data, {
      printerName: 'RECEIPT',
      preview: false,
      width: '170px',               //  width of content body
      margin: '15 15 15 15',            // margin of content body
      copies: 1,                   
      silent : true
  })
  .then(() => {
    // some code ...
    console.log("done");
    return "Printing successful.."
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return "Something went wrong."
});
```

I am accessing this method on the react side like:

```
  handlePrint = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ipcRenderer.send('print', this.state.cheques, this.state.total);
  }
```

How would I be able to return the status message if the printing is successful or if there is an error to the renderer?

Answer (score 0):

You must use **event.reply()** function from **ipcMain.on()**

Example with your code.

*Main process.* ***Electron***

```
ipcMain.on('print', (event, results, total) => {
// some code

.then(() => {
 // some code ...
 event.reply('print', 'Printing successful..')

}).catch((error) => {
 event.reply('print', 'Something went wrong.')
});
```

*Renderer Process (web page).* ***React***

```
ipcRenderer.on('print', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "Printing successful.." or "Something went wrong."
})
```

You can allocate the render process code in the **componentDidMount()** or  **useEffect()** of your component or your App.js

This is the way to transfer data from **Main Process** to **Render Process** in execute time as return function.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages